# Problems about including appcompat in my old project

Tags: android, android-studio

Good day everybody.

I am trying to use in my project v7 library in my project.

I have already download it from the SDK manager. But, when I try to compile my project it emerges an issue. It tells that I have already define those values, but I don't know where are this values are coming from.

```
{project_path}\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(219) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(219) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(219) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
Error:(219) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(219) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
Error:(245) Attribute "dividerPadding" has already been defined
Error:(245) Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined
Error:(251) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(259) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "logo" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "customNavigationLayout" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
Error:(266) Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
Error:(269) Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
Error:(269) Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(272) Attribute "itemTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:(272) Attribute "itemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(272) Attribute "preserveIconSpacing" has already been defined
Error:(273) Attribute "iconifiedByDefault" has already been defined
Error:(273) Attribute "queryHint" has already been defined
Error:(292) Attribute "tabBackground" has already been defined
Error:(295) Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
Error:(295) Attribute "windowNoTitle" has already been defined
Error:(295) Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(295) Attribute "windowActionModeOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(295) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" has already been defined
Error:(295) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" has already been defined
...
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':libraryIndicators')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':librarySlide')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

I don't know if there is an issue with the other projects that I'm trying to compile too, with it.

Comment: What are these other projects (facebookSDK, libraryIndicators, etc.)? Do any these have appcompat as a dependency?

Comment: Those were some integrations used before. They don't have a appcompat dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like all of the objects listed in the first text dump have been defined elsewhere in the code. Try commenting these items out of values.xml and see if it compiles then.